# countdown from 200 to 0 in multiples of x. X is a value input by the user (python)

Tags: python, countdown

I wanted to make a program that counts down from 200 to 0 in multiples of "x". "x" is a number that the user inputs. For example, if the user inputs "5", I want the program to print a list that begins with 200,195,190,185,180... and ends with 0. This is the code I have written so far:

```
rows = int(input('What number? '))
i = 1
for i in range(200,-1,rows):
 print (200- i * rows)
i = i + 1
```

Right now it's telling me that "for i in range" can only have one argument, but when I make the argument 0, it doesn't run. When I make the argument 200, the program subtracts "x" from two hundred 200 times. How can I get the program to stop the list at 0?

Comment: Try to use while loop for simpler code.

Comment: shouldn't your third argument be negative? since you are tying to decrese it by that amount.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is negate rows like this:

```
rows = int(input('What number? '))

for i in range(200, -1, -rows):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to increment `i` manually in Python.

`range(a, b, step)` is a range from `a` inclusive to `b` exclusive with preset `step`. Please [see](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).

For your purpose, the following would be suitable:

```
print(i) for i in reversed(range(1, 200+1, x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
rows = int(input('What number? '))
i = 1
for i in range(1, int(200/rows)+1):
    print (200- i*rows)
```